# VS Code terminal not working anymore (WSL)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i've been using vscode terminal for a while and the terminal suddenly stopped working. Nothing appears on it. If i close it and try to open a new terminal nothing happens. Also when i run the cmd and try to start wsl, it doesn't work and when i open the debian app, the terminal doesn't show anything.
So I'm confused as what is not working since wsl seem to not work but also the vscode terminal doesn't even show the cmd.
I am not getting any error.

FIXED : Making a full reboot of Windows fixed it for me. Hold `shift` while clicking on restart in the Windows menu to make a full reboot of Windows.

Comment: ***it doesn't work and when i open the debian app*** You probably need to look into WSL support if it does not work. Maybe it's this: [https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5836](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5836)